# как изменить url на сайте, открытом через локальный сервер

Tags: url

допустим, что ссылка сайта web/index2.php, а я хочу, чтобы отображалось как web/index.php. как это сделать?

Comment: переименовать файл index2.php в index.php?

Comment: нет, ну у меня уже есть index.php. мне нужно, чтобы и index2.php был будто index.php. так надо просто кода много - разделил. там свои приблуды. мне именно нужно отображать в адресной строке другой адрес. вот можно это как-то сделать? делают же всякие человеко читаемые ссылки, но там именно в параметрах прикол. а мне немного другое нужно. или то, что я хочу, нельзя изменить?

Answer (score 0):

Способы добиться, чтобы по разным ссылкам открывалась одна и та же страница:

## Самый простой: скопировать файл

Скопировать файл index.php в index2.php (пример в linux-консоли):

```
cp index.php index2.php
```

## Более сложный: сделать симлинк

```
ln -s index.php index2.php
```

В этом случае при редактировании файла index.php содержимое index2.php также изменится. Что такое [симлинк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Если используете веб-сервер Apache, убедитесь, что опция `FollowSymLinks` включена.

## Более правильный: настроить веб-сервер

Для примера я покажу как это делается в Apache. Запишите в файл `.htaccess` в каталоге, где находится `index.php`, следующее:

```
# включаем перезапись ссылок
RewriteEngine on
# Если запрашиваемый адрес не является каталогом на диске
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# и если запрашиваемый адрес не является файлом на диске
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# то перезаписываем адрес на index.php
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Таким образом, если файл `index2.php` не будет существовать на диске, сработает файл `index.php`. Если будет, то выведется его содержимое